# How can i add Declarative Services support to embedded felix in Netbeans?

Tags: netbeans, osgi, apache-felix, declarative-services

In netbeans, embedded felix does not support DS.How can we add Felix Service Component Runtime to embedded felix in netbeans.

Answer (score 1):

Declarative Services is implemented by an ordinary bundle, called SCR (Service Component Runtime). Simply install that bundle! Look for SCR on the Felix downloads page: http://felix.apache.org/downloads.cgi