# Using declarative services with embedded Felix framework

Tags: osgi, apache-felix, declarative-services

I am developing a desktop OSGi app with declarative services on Mac OS X using Netbeans and Maven. I start the Felix framework from within a Java application and load my OSGi bundles using `AutoProcessor.process()`.

However, I cannot get services referenced in other services to activate. As an example, I have a service `AImpl` which refers to service `B` as follows:

```
interface A {}

interface B {}

@Component
@Service(A.class)
class AImpl implements A {
    @Reference(strategy = EVENT)
    B b;
    ...
}

@Component
@Service(B.class)
class BImpl implements B { ... }
```

The value of `AImpl.b` is always `null` after I have created a bundle of type `A`.

My code to start the Felix framework looks like this:

```
Map felixConfiguration = ...;

try {
    framework = new Felix(felixConfiguration);
    framework.init();

    final BundleContext frameworkBundleContext = framework.
                getBundleContext();

    AutoProcessor.process(felixConfiguration, frameworkBundleContext);

    framework.start();

    framework.waitForStop(0);
    System.exit(0);

} catch (Exception ex) {
    log.error("Could not start framework", ex);
    System.exit(-1);
}
```

`felixConfiguration` contains – amongst many other things – the definition of the directory from which the bundles containing the DS services are to be loaded.

However, I get error messages like the following:

```
 DEBUG: BundleA (12): [AImpl(6)] Updating target filters
 DEBUG: BundleA (12): [AImpl(6)] No change in target property for dependency b: currently registered: false
 DEBUG: BundleA (12): [AImpl(6)] No existing service listener to unregister for dependency b
 DEBUG: BundleA (12): [AImpl(6)] Setting target property for dependency b to null
 DEBUG: BundleA (12): [AImpl(6)] New service tracker for b, initial active: false, previous references: {}
 DEBUG: BundleA (12): [AImpl(6)] dm b tracker reset (closed)
 DEBUG: BundleA (12): [AImpl(6)] dm b tracker opened
 DEBUG: BundleA (12): [AImpl(6)] registering service listener for dependency b
 DEBUG: BundleA (12): [AImpl(6)] Component enabled
 DEBUG: BundleA (12): [AImpl(6)] ActivateInternal
 DEBUG: BundleA (12): [AImpl(6)] Activating component from state 4
 DEBUG: BundleA (12): [AImpl(6)] Dependency not satisfied: b
 DEBUG: BundleA (12): [AImpl(6)] Not all dependencies satisfied, cannot activate
```

It seems to me that some SCR code is missing that will make the Felix framework deal with DS services. I have included `org.apache.felix.scr-1.8.2.jar` (and alternatively `org.apache.felix.scr-2.0.2.jar` and `org.apache.felix.scr.compat-1.0.2.jar`) in the dependencies, but that does not seem to be enough.

An additional symptom, which I assume is related to the same problem: `gogo` starts but doesn't recognise commands like `help`, `lb` etc., although all three bundles (command, runtime, shell) are available.

I have simplified the examples and changed the names of the parties involved to protect the innocent :-) I hope that the structure is clear enough to show what I am trying to do and what is not working.

I have googled terms like `felix ds embedded` and found articles like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19152649/how-can-i-add-declarative-services-support-to-embedded-felix-in-netbeans), which make it sound as easy as I wish it was. Clearly I am making a mistake somewhere: I'd be grateful for pointers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you do looks good at first glance. It is difficult to tell without all details.

You seem to be using the scr annotations. As there are standard DS annotations now I propose you give them a try. I got a [full example here](http://liquid-reality.de/display/liquid/2015/06/30/Apache+Karaf+Tutorial+part+10+-+Declarative+services).

I typically use karaf for my examples but it should also work in plain felix.

One thing your could try is to install your bundles into karaf and use the karaf shell to analyze if there is anything strange. Just install the scr feature and put your bundles into the deploy dir.

If that works then your bundle are correct and there is probably a problem with your felix deployment.

In any case you should check that all bundles can be resolved. Of course this is a bit difficult as long as the shell does not work.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback: I'll go through your points one-by-one and see if I can isolate the problem. I infer from your reply that no special steps are required when starting declarative services from an embedded Felix framework other than loading an appropriate `org.apache.felix.scr` bundle.

Comment: Yes. The scr bundle should be enough. For the new features you might also need a reasonably new Felix but I am not sure if that is required at all.

What you could try is to retrieve the BundleContext from the Framework and  go through the bundles in a loop to print their state.
In tests I also often simply start each bundle in the loop. This will then print out an exception if the start or resolve is not successful.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the problem after stripping the application right down to the basics, which in this case is the code to start the Felix framework.

The key to the problem was the recognition that an OSGi framework embedded in a normal Java program is a meeting of two worlds: bundles and POJOs. These days lots of POJOs are distributed with OSGi-compatible manifests, but they are still POJOs and not bundles. But I was sticking everything with an OSGi manifest into the bundles directory and loading them with `AutoProcessor.process()`. This included things like `org.apache.felix.framework` and `org.apache.felix.main`, but also various POJOs dealing with logging. That seems to have caused the behaviour described above.

I fixed this by linking `org.apache.felix.framework`, `org.apache.felix.main` and the logging POJOs in the classic fashion and excluding them from `AutoProcessor.process()`.

Unfortunately, `slf4j-api` seems to lead a double life, and there are lots of bundles out there, some of which I am using, which need it as a bundle. Rather than experiment with loading it twice (classical linking and `AutoProcessor.process()`) I simply added `pax-logging-api` and `pax-logging-service` to my bundles directory and let `AutoProcessor.process()` load them instead.

It all makes perfect sense with hindsight ;-)